# why do tf2 lags a lot on ubuntu?

Tags: games, steam

When I try playing TF2 on my PC, the game runs with extreme lag, making it nearly impossible to play. Here are specs of my PC: Intel i3 4th gen, 3.4Ghz. RAM: 4 GB. No graphics card, Intel integrated GPU. TF2 was running smoothly on windows on the same machine, but on Ubuntu its lagging extremely. (I am a new ubuntu user :D)

Comment: Probably because of the garbage support for intel GPUs on linux?

Answer (score 0):

I think the lag comes from network connect. In my case, I use an almost same machine as you, TF2 runs OK. When I see lag, the ping goes high.

My machine is an Dell XPS-L421X with 4G RAM, and an "Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller".

Otherwise the TF2 is full of bugs. many times it crash with a messagebox show "failed to lock vertex buffer in CMeshDX8::....." or "Out of memory".

I heard that the Intel video card driver not cache something on Ubuntu but it does in Windows which can faster the game's loading, but no effect the running speed. The whole "loading" progress need 3 minutes.